# cannot use mediafire java api

Tags: java, mediafire

Following this link,

http://www.mediafire.com/developers/sdks_and_tools/java/basics/

after downloading from

https://github.com/MediaFire/mediafire-java-sdk/releases

i added the content from `mediafire-java-sdk-3.2.1\src\main\java\com` to my netbeans project as there were no jars to add like a library. This is the result when adding the code from `Custom Implementations of Interfaces used by Configuration (RECOMMENDED)`

[image]

The Configuration class from `com.mediafire.sdk.config` was correct but it doesnt seem to have any `Builder` in it, any suggestions to make this code run?

**PD:** neither the code from https://github.com/MediaFire/mediafire-java-sdk/wiki seems to work.

```
MFConfigurationBuilder mfConfigurationBuilder = new MFConfigurationBuilder(yourAppId);
MFConfiguration mfConfiguration = mfConfigurationBuilder.build();
```

Nothing of this is found in any package.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation is out of date. More information in their [forum](http://forum.mediafiredev.com/showthread.php?573-Java-SDK-and-Documentation)

Please refer to the older github version if you insist on using Java API or wait until new documentation is released.

https://github.com/MediaFire/mediafire-java-sdk/tree/04fbd929d5c95f510361ba50d95301f3ad3c4b5e